# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v9.0, or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have deployed my website to the server and when I try to access it using URL, I am getting the below error 
    Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v9.0, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I even added the reference to the above DLL but still getting the error. When I ran the code which is stored iin server using visual studio, It is working fine but I am getting this error when tried the same with URL

Please help

Comment: Can you find the DLL for it anywhere in the deployment folder?

Comment: I added the reference to this DLL.

Answer (score 0):

References only act as paths to DLLs.  If you add a reference to a DLL, and the host machine does not have it.  You'll get the expected exception.

The DLLs must be present somewhere on your server.
I believe you can install Microsoft Office Tools on your Server.

If not, you can copy the DLL you're referencing to a folder that will be deploed with your application.  You'll also need to remove the reference and re-add it using the path local to your application for this to work.